# Database connection error in wordpress

Tags: mysql, wordpress

My site is on Wordpress and is hosted on a VPS server. The traffic is not much but the database connect error is displayed many times, and then I had to restart MySQL.

I've checked the MySQL error file log. Here is a certain portion of the log.

```
140310 01:13:26 mysqld_safe mysqld from pid file /var/lib/mysql/server.gosoftnep.com.pid ended
140310 01:13:26 mysqld_safe Starting mysqld daemon with databases from /var/lib/mysql
140310  1:13:26 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
140310  1:13:26 InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
140310  1:13:26 InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
140310  1:13:26 InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3
140310  1:13:26 InnoDB: Using Linux native AIO
140310  1:13:26 InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 128.0M
140310  1:13:26 InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
140310  1:13:26 InnoDB: highest supported file format is Barracuda.
140310  1:13:26  InnoDB: Waiting for the background threads to start
140310  1:13:27 InnoDB: 5.5.36 started; log sequence number 12082242998
140310  1:13:27 [Note] Server hostname (bind-address): '0.0.0.0'; port: 3306
140310  1:13:27 [Note]   - '0.0.0.0' resolves to '0.0.0.0';
140310  1:13:27 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '0.0.0.0'.
140310  1:13:27 [Note] Event Scheduler: Loaded 0 events
140310  1:13:27 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld: ready for connections.
Version: '5.5.36-cll'  socket: '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock'  port: 3306  MySQL Community Server (GPL)
140310 01:13:32 mysqld_safe A mysqld process already exists
140310  5:52:48 [Warning] IP address '58.118.152.8' could not be resolved: Temporary failure in name resolution
140310 12:27:37 mysqld_safe Number of processes running now: 0
140310 12:27:38 mysqld_safe mysqld restarted
140310 12:27:44 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
140310 12:27:45 InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
140310 12:27:45 InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
140310 12:27:45 InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3
140310 12:27:45 InnoDB: Using Linux native AIO
140310 12:27:47 InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 128.0M
140310 12:27:49 InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
140310 12:27:50 InnoDB: highest supported file format is Barracuda.
InnoDB: Log scan progressed past the checkpoint lsn 12354557593
140310 12:27:52  InnoDB: Database was not shut down normally!
InnoDB: Starting crash recovery.
InnoDB: Reading tablespace information from the .ibd files...
InnoDB: Restoring possible half-written data pages from the doublewrite
InnoDB: buffer...
InnoDB: Doing recovery: scanned up to log sequence number 12354588661
140310 12:28:05  InnoDB: Starting an apply batch of log records to the database...
InnoDB: Progress in percents: 43 44 45 46 47 48 49 50 51 52 53 54 55 56 57 58 59 60 61 62 63 64 65 66 67 68 69 70 71 72 73 74 75 76 77 78 79 80 81 82 83 84 85 86 87 88 89 90 91 92 93 94 95 96 97 98 99 
InnoDB: Apply batch completed
140310 12:28:07  InnoDB: Waiting for the background threads to start
140310 12:28:08 InnoDB: 5.5.36 started; log sequence number 12354588661
140310 12:28:08 [Note] Server hostname (bind-address): '0.0.0.0'; port: 3306
140310 12:28:08 [Note]   - '0.0.0.0' resolves to '0.0.0.0';
140310 12:28:08 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '0.0.0.0'.
140310 12:28:12 [Note] Event Scheduler: Loaded 0 events
140310 12:28:12 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld: ready for connections.
Version: '5.5.36-cll'  socket: '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock'  port: 3306  MySQL Community Server (GPL)
140311 11:51:59 [Warning] IP address '61.160.249.239' could not be resolved: Name or service not known
140312  9:23:21 [Warning] IP address '183.60.107.205' could not be resolved: Name or service not known
140313  0:33:47 [Warning] IP address '221.228.231.59' could not be resolved: Name or service not known
140313  7:33:05 [Warning] IP address '61.147.103.160' could not be resolved: Name or service not known
140313 20:42:42 [Warning] IP address '124.89.32.242' could not be resolved: Name or service not known
140313 23:33:38 mysqld_safe Number of processes running now: 0
140313 23:33:38 mysqld_safe mysqld restarted
140313 23:34:09 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
140313 23:34:14 InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
140313 23:34:14 InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
140313 23:34:14 InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3
140313 23:34:14 InnoDB: Using Linux native AIO
140313 23:34:17 InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 128.0M
140313 23:34:20 InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
140313 23:34:30 mysqld_safe mysqld from pid file /var/lib/mysql/server.gosoftnep.com.pid ended
140314 02:55:09 mysqld_safe Starting mysqld daemon with databases from /var/lib/mysql
140314  2:55:10 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
140314  2:55:10 InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
140314  2:55:10 InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
140314  2:55:10 InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3
140314  2:55:10 InnoDB: Using Linux native AIO
140314  2:55:10 InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 128.0M
140314  2:55:10 InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
140314  2:55:10 InnoDB: highest supported file format is Barracuda.
InnoDB: Log scan progressed past the checkpoint lsn 14587500130
140314  2:55:10  InnoDB: Database was not shut down normally!
InnoDB: Starting crash recovery.
InnoDB: Reading tablespace information from the .ibd files...
InnoDB: Restoring possible half-written data pages from the doublewrite
InnoDB: buffer...
InnoDB: Doing recovery: scanned up to log sequence number 14587535674
140314  2:55:11  InnoDB: Starting an apply batch of log records to the database...
InnoDB: Progress in percents: 67 68 69 70 71 72 73 74 75 76 77 78 79 80 81 82 83 84 85 86 87 88 89 90 91 92 93 94 95 96 97 98 99 
InnoDB: Apply batch completed
140314  2:55:11  InnoDB: Waiting for the background threads to start
140314  2:55:12 InnoDB: 5.5.36 started; log sequence number 14587535674
140314  2:55:12 [Note] Server hostname (bind-address): '0.0.0.0'; port: 3306
140314  2:55:12 [Note]   - '0.0.0.0' resolves to '0.0.0.0';
140314  2:55:12 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '0.0.0.0'.
140314  2:55:12 [Note] Event Scheduler: Loaded 0 events
140314  2:55:12 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld: ready for connections.
Version: '5.5.36-cll'  socket: '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock'  port: 3306  MySQL Community Server (GPL)
```

I do not understand anything about this. Could anyone explain the issue to me or suggest a fix?

Comment: Looks like it crashed and had to do a data recovery process. Is it working now?

Comment: Hi Ed Cattrell,
Yes, the site is working but the database connection error is displayed often and I've to restart mysql. I don't know why this is happening. Any suggestion?

Comment: Without more information, I don't know. Does this VPS host other sites? How heavy is your traffic? What is the result of this query: `SELECT @@max_connections`?

Comment: This is only site on the VPS host and there is only 1 to 5 concurrent visitor on the site.
I've run the query you mentioned and "Array ( [0] => 151 [@@max_connections] => 151 )" this is the result.

Comment: There's some suspicious stuff in that log. For example, it tries to resolve a bunch of IP addresses. That makes it sound like you have a master/slave or cluster setup. Do you? If so, is the log above from the actual machine to which Wordpress is connecting? What's happening on those other servers?

Comment: Yes, the log is from the server.  I do not know about master/slave or cluster setup. How do I get to know? Where shall I check?
I did run maldet and found 4 hits and moved to volt , nothing on mysql.

Comment: If you found malware you should seriously consider nuking the setup and rebuilding. You can try `SHOW SLAVE HOSTS` and `SHOW SLAVE STATUS` to see if you have a master/slave setup.

Comment: We moved the site to other server. Lets see how it does. Thank you Ed for the all the replies. I'll look for show slave host and show slave status.